# Please, correct the sentece

Tags: american-english

I believe this doesn't sound natural. Could you correct the sentence if I'm wrong?

"I can't say that I got 100% of what you've wrote on these [scientific] papers"

Answer (score 1):

It's a little clumsy, but (to me) the intent is clear:

> "I'm not sure that I understood everything that was in those [scientific] papers."

If I was to minimally change the original sentence, I'd probably say:

> "I can't say that I understood 100% of what you've written in those [scientific] papers."

Answer (score 1):

The sentence sounds normal to me, but it would sound a bit unsophisticated if you wrote like that in a more formal writing situation. I think John Burger's sentences are good alternatives for those cases, though.

For informal spoken language, however, I think your original sentence works perfectly; the fact that it's more colloquial/informal, if anything, actually makes it sound more authentic because it doesn't sound like something you would learn out of a textbook.

The only real grammatical problem is that it should say either "what you wrote" or "what you've written", the first one being past tense and the second one being past perfect tense. Try not to mix up your tenses. However, even native English speakers will mix up their tenses from time to time, so don't worry too much about it.